# Qt: Sorting is wrong when using QSortFilterProxyModel on number strings and getting wrong column text

Tags: qt, sorting, qtreeview

i have simple model view treeview with QSortFilterProxyModel proxy to sort the columns and QStandardItemModel as the model
in each columns there are string that gets sorted fine but in columns that contains number ( as strings ) the sorting wrong .
say i have 9,12,1 (each number in different column when i sort them im getting 1,12,9 or 12,1,9 but never in the right order .
like 1,9,12 or 12,9,1 why ?
also i notice that when i sort row by column , when i try to get the new column text with    `m_model->item(iSelectedRow,0)->text();`
im getting the initial column text but never the new sorted column text. why ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's because by default, QSortFilterProxyModel sorts by DisplayRole. If that returns a string, it will sort the string.
To have the model sort by some other value, define a custom sort role in the source model and set it on the proxy:

```
class MyModel {
   ...
   enum Role {
      SortRole=Qt::UserRole
   };
   QVariant data( ... ) const {
       ...
       switch ( role ) {
       case Qt::DisplayRole:
           return value as string;
       case SortRole:
           return value as int;
       }
   }
};

...
sortfilterproxy->setSortRole( MyModel::SortRole );
```

Your second question: What is m_model? The source model, or the sortfilterproxymodel? The former is never changed by sorting, the sorting happens only in the proxy.

Comment: thanks for the reply m_model is QStandardItemModel
i dont understand how can i updated the model after the sorting ?
so when i get the column text it will give me the right one

Comment: Don't try to edit the source model, but ask the sort filter proxy for the data instead of the source model.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld , is there an intuitive way to code for 'sort by int if the column is full of ints, but sort by string if column is full of strings'?

Comment: @10mjg Make sure to return the respective type for the respective column, when role is SortRole, and it should work.

Answer (score 3):

If you sort the strings "9", "12" and "1" you will get "1", "12", "9" (lexicographic sorting). If you want them sorted as numbers, you have to subclass the QSortFilterProxyModel  and reimplement the lessThan member function where you could just use QString::toInt().

You can find out all of this by studying the excelent [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qsortfilterproxymodel.html), where you also find information about  mapToSource(), mapFromSource(), mapSelectionToSource(), and mapSelectionFromSource() to convert source QModelIndexes to sorted/filtered model indexes or vice versa.

Comment: No need to reimplement lessThan() and use toInt() (which would be highly inefficient if the variant stores a string), just use setSortRole().

Comment: Excellent comment and answer! It looks like I have to study the documentation more ;-)

Answer (score 1):

use QStandardItem::setData() when filling your table as shown below. Then all will work as expected.

below lines from Qt documentation

```
virtual void QStandardItem::setData(const QVariant & value, int role = Qt::UserRole + 1)
```

Here is simple usage of set data.

```
item->setData(intData, Qt::DisplayRole);
```