# QSortFilterProxyModel does not apply SortRole

Tags: python, qt, sorting, model

I have a QTableView with a subclassed QSqlQueryModel and a QSortFilterProxyModel in between. Some columns in the underlying database contain floating point numbers and they get sorted as they were strings. Example:

```
-0.06
-1.45
 0.02
 0.05
 ...
```

Using Python/PyQt, I implemented the outlined solution from [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568161/qt-sorting-is-wrong-when-using-qsortfilterproxymodel-on-number-strings-and-gett) but it doesn't work.

**My subclassed QSqlQueryModel:**

```
class CatalogModel(QSqlQueryModel):

  SortRole = Qt.UserRole + 1

  def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
    col = index.column()
    data = super(CatalogModel, self).data(index, role)

    print role == self.SortRole     # always False

    if role == self.SortRole:
      if col in (2,3,4):
        return data.toFloat()[0]

    return data
```

**Setting up the proxy:**

```
proxy = QSortFilterProxyModel(self)
proxy.setSortRole(CatalogModel.SortRole)
```

My own SortRole does not arrive in my model and the columns with float numbers are still sorted like strings.
Why does this solution not work? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [latest official documentation](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qdoc/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#sorting):

> Behind the scene, the view calls the sort() virtual function on the model to reorder the data in the model. To make your data sortable, you can either implement sort() in your model, or use a QSortFilterProxyModel to wrap your model -- QSortFilterProxyModel provides a generic sort() reimplementation that operates on the sortRole() (Qt::DisplayRole by default) of the items and that understands several data types, including int, QString, and QDateTime. For hierarchical models, sorting is applied recursively to all child items. String comparisons are case sensitive by default; this can be changed by setting the sortCaseSensitivity property.

Implement your own sort() could also be one option, but:

> An alternative approach to sorting is to disable sorting on the view and to impose a certain order to the user. This is done by explicitly calling sort() with the desired column and order as arguments on the QSortFilterProxyModel (or on the original model if it implements sort()). For example:

```
    proxyModel->sort(2, Qt::AscendingOrder);
```

> QSortFilterProxyModel can be sorted by column -1, in which case it returns to the sort order of the underlying source model.

You could pass -1 to that method in the following manner:

```
proxy = QSortFilterProxyModel(self);
proxy.setSortRole(CatalogModel.SortRole);
proxy.sort(-1, Qt.AscendingOrder);
```

Note that you pasted the two lines there without semi-colon. The code would not even compile like that due to syntax errors. It is better to paste correct code.

If it does not work, just implement your sorting.

Comment: I might look into the reimplementation of `sort` in my source model. Right now, the reimplementation of `lessThan` of the proxy model works quite good. What would be the better approach?

(btw: Python doesn't require a semicolon at the end of line.)

Comment: @AndreasN: what is wrong about the aforementioned approach? lessThan is meant for more complex sorting algorithm if I understand correctly when the logic is significantly different from the default which does not seem to be the with float sorting.

Comment: if you mean by 'aforementioned' setting a custom sort role and reacting to that in the model, then that didn't work. Numbers are sorted as strings. If you mean reimplementing `sort` of my QSqlQueryModel subclass, then how would I do that? Will setting a new query with the appropriate `order by` clause suffice? However, that will fetch all the data from the database again.

Comment: @AndreasN: can you provide a self-contained example that "did not work"? Also, for sorting, you just inherit, and reimplement the method. It is not more difficult than that. :-)

Comment: I should be able to provide a small example. You also say 'just inherit and reimplement the method'. How do I do that (see my last comment)? My subclass does not handle the data. The base class (QSqlQueryModel) does.

Comment: @AndreasN: so what? That is basic C++ that subclasses only extend the functionality of the base class...

Comment: Yes, but `sort()` is not implemented in QSqlQueryModel, which means it is inherited by QAbstractTableModel, which means it is inherited from QAbstractItemModel. And there it does nothing. So my implementation of `sort()` would replace the models existing SQL query with a new one containing a proper `order by <field>`. '<field>' would be determined by the section parameter. What I really wanted to know is if this is a good or a bad practice. These are my first steps with QtSql. Apologies, if I expressed myself too vaguely in the previous comments. :)

Comment: @AndreasN: have you resolved the nitty-gritty details?

Comment: Yes, I finally resolved it. My model actually returned strings instead of numbers. That's why it's got sorted the wrong way. Then, I got sorting working as expected by using the proxys sort role. BUT: UserRole won't work here, because at some point the role is passed to QSqlQueryModel, and that returns invalid QVariant, because the role is not DisplayRole or EditRole. So in my model I use DisplayRole for returning custom number formats and EditRole for returning plain numbers. As this is my solution, I simply accept here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch sorting on I think. Something like:

```
proxy.sort(-1, Qt.AscendingOrder);
```

According to docs http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsortfilterproxymodel.html column `-1` will switch on the sorting of the underlying model. Which is probably what you need.