# Program crashes after defining new role for model

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5.4

I tried to implement a new model that sorts numerically as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568161/qt-sorting-is-wrong-when-using-qsortfilterproxymodel-on-number-strings-and-gett).

It looks like this:

```
#ifndef NUMERICMODEL_H
#define NUMERICMODEL_H

#include <QStandardItemModel>

class NumericModel : public QStandardItemModel
{
public:

    enum Role {
        SortRole=Qt::UserRole
    };

    NumericModel() {}
    ~NumericModel() {}

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const {

        switch ( role ) {
            case Qt::DisplayRole:
                return index.data().toString();
            case SortRole:
                return index.data().toUInt();
            default:
                return index.data().toString();
        }

    }

};

#endif // NUMERICMODEL_H
```

I am setting the sort role like this:

```
QSortFilterProxyModel * proxyModel = new QSortFilterProxyModel(this);
proxyModel->setSourceModel(&m_movesModel);
proxyModel->setSortRole(NumericModel::SortRole);
qDebug() << __LINE__;
ui->tableView_Moves->setModel(proxyModel);qDebug() << __LINE__;
ui->tableView_Moves->resizeColumnsToContents();qDebug() << __LINE__;
```

However my program crashes in the last line, when calling `ui->tableView_Moves->resizeColumnsToContents()`.

Answer (score 0):

why you are subleasing `QStandardItemModel`? 
This is not needed since this model handles any kind of roles! Just set them.

Anyway your implementation lead to infinitive recursion!

The answer you provided is incomplete. You have to understand that `QStandardItemModel` can store any kind of data it can be `QString`, it can be `int` or `double` (and other types see [doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#lessThan)). Default compare method for `QSortFilterProxyModel` handles all of this types so problem is of comparing strings with numbers, so problem is what type exactly `QVariant` stores. Linked answer tries enforce uniform type used for sorting and this solution is quite poor.

IMO it is safer to subclass `QSortFilterProxyModel` like that:

```
bool MyUIntSortFilterProxyModel::lessThan(const QModelIndex & left, 
                                          const QModelIndex & right ) const {
    int cmpRole = sortRole();
    return left.data(cmpRole).toUInt()<right.data(cmpRole).toUInt();
}
```

Comment: In [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568161/qt-sorting-is-wrong-when-using-qsortfilterproxymodel-on-number-strings-and-gett#comment7744654_6569116) comment, it says that this would be inefficient.
You say I can just set a role without creating my own class, how?

Comment: this is in different context. If you what improve performance then you should provide own model by subclassing `QAbstractTableModel` not `QStandardItemModel`, but probably it will be to tough for you.

Comment: I came up with my own solution, thanks to your hints. It works for me now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27815921/2102827) I now know that my data function was incomplete. Instead of going through all possible cases manually, I just asked for my specific case and then called the data function of the base class.

```
QVariant data(const QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const {

    if (role == SortRole) {
        return index.data().toUInt();
    }

    return QStandardItemModel::data(index, role);

}
```